# Mongo DB Map/Reduce - Reduce doesnt get called

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dictionary, mapreduce, reduce

I'm trying to do a simple map reduce in the Mongo shell, but the reduce function never gets called. This is my code :

```
db.sellers.mapReduce( 
    function(){ emit( this._id, 'Map') } , 
    function(k,vs){ return 'Reduce' }, 
    { out: { inline: 1}})
```

And the result is

```
{
"results" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4da0bdb56bd728c276911e1a"),
        "value" : "Map"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("4da0df9a6bd728c276911e1b"),
        "value" : "Map"
    }
],
"timeMillis" : 0,
"counts" : {
    "input" : 2,
    "emit" : 2,
    "output" : 2
},
"ok" : 1,
```

}

Whats wrong?

I'm using MongoDB 1.8.1 32 bit on Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The purpose of `reduce` is to, *ekhem*, reduce the set of values associated with a given key into a one value (aggregate results). If you emit only one value for each MapReduce key, there is not need for reduce, all the work is done. But if you emit two pairs for a given `_id`, reduce will be called:

```
emit(this._id, 'Map1');
emit(this._id, 'Map2');
```

this will call reduce with the following parameters:

```
reduce(_id, ['Map1', 'Map2'])
```

More likely you will want to use `_id` for MapReduce key when filtering dataset: `emit` only when given record fulfills some condition. But again, `reduce` won't be called in this case, which is expected.

Comment: You're right Tomasz. I picked this example out of the MongoDB docs. It would help Map/Reduce noobs like myself very much if this was clearly mentioned. A humble "green check" for you!

Comment: Still could be inferred that reduce will receive, using your example, reduce(_id, ['Map1']) in the case of only 1 item emitted. Not passing through reduce breaks my result set.

Comment: I think that not calling reduce on single values is a strange implementation choice. So everytime you change the structure of the result of `map` you also have to adjust `reduce` in order to get uniform results in case of single value `map` results.

Comment: Yeah, this is a real pain. I'm aggregating a large dataset, and it basically means I can't aggregate sets that only contain one object. Weird implementation choice...

Answer (score 6):

Well, the MongoDB does not call Reduce function on a key if there is only one value for it.

In my opinion, this is bad. It should be left to my reducer code to decide whether to skip a singular value or do some operation on it.

Now, if I have to do some operation on singular value, I end up writing the finalize function and in the finalize, I try to differentiate which value has gone through the reducer or which not.

I am very sure, it does not happen this way in case of Hadoop.

Comment: Thank you! this is very counter intuitive, part of the reducers jobs is to build the item in a certain way, that might very well be different.

Answer (score 1):

**Map reduce will collect values with a common key into a single value.**

In this case nothing is to be done because each value emitted by map has a different key. No reduction is needed.

```
db.sellers.mapReduce( 
    function(){ emit( this._id, 'Map') } , 
    function(k,vs){ return 'Reduce' }, 
    { out: { inline: 1}})
```

*This is not entirely clear from reading the documentation.*

If you wanted to call reduce, you might hardcode an ID like this:

```
db.sellers.mapReduce( 
    function(){ emit( 1, 'Map') } , 
    function(k,vs){ return 'Reduce' }, 
    { out: { inline: 1}})
```

Now all the values emitted by map will be reduced until only one remains.

Answer (score 1):

It should also be mentioned that, according to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function), "MongoDB can invoke the reduce function more than once for the same key. In this case, the previous output from the reduce function for that key will become one of the input values to the next reduce function invocation for that key.".

Also, `reduce` should be associative, commutative and idempotent:

```
reduce(key, [ C, reduce(key, [ A, B ]) ] ) == reduce( key, [ C, A, B ] )
reduce( key, [ reduce(key, valuesArray) ] ) == reduce( key, valuesArray )
reduce( key, [ A, B ] ) == reduce( key, [ B, A ] )
```

So, it means that the `reduce` function should be ready to receive the object which is the result of the previous invocation of itself. Which (at least for me, personally) means that the best way to implement `mapReduce` is to make the `map` function to (if possible) emit values in the same format as the `reduce` function returns. Then the `reduce` function can be implemented to support only one input format. And, as a result, even if there's only one object emitted by `map` (and the invocation of `reduce` is skipped, as a result), in the final result of the `mapReduce`, the value for the keys for which the `reduce` was never called will still be in the same format as the value for the rest of the keys.

For instance, if we have the following document structure:

```
{ 
    "foo": <some_string>,
    "status": ("foo"|"bar")
}
```

the `map` function may be as follows:

```
function() {
    var value = {
       "num_total": 1,
       "num_foos": 0,
       "num_bars": 0
    };

    if (this.status == "foo") {
        value["num_foos"] += 1;
    }

    if (this.status == "bar") {
        value["num_bars"] += 1;
    }

    emit(this.foo, value);
}
```

and the `reduce` function will be:

```
function(key, values) {
    var reduced = {
       "num_total": 0,
       "num_foos": 0,
       "num_bars": 0
    };

    values.forEach(function(val) {
        reduced["num_total"] += val["num_total"];
        reduced["num_foos"] += val["num_foos"];
        reduced["num_bars"] += val["num_bars"];
    });

    return reduced;
}
```